# Div 100% height displaying as 0px?

Tags: html, css, height

I'm currently building a website and have a small problem that i cant seem to tackle, I have created a div with a height of 100%, inside that div is a slider div also with a height of 100%, the problem is the first div displays a height of 0px so that the div that should come below the slider div displays behind the slider div, anyone that can help me?

Here's my code:

```
.slider-container {
    width:                              100%;
    min-height:                         100%;
    background-color:                   white;
    float:                              left;
}

.main-content {
    width:                              100%;
    height:                             1000px;
    background-color:                   pink;
    float:                              left;
}

.column {
    width:                              31%;
    height:                             auto;
    background-color:                   orange;
    float:                              left
}

/* SLIDER */

.caption {
    width:                              500px;
    background-image:                   url("..//img/caption-bg.png");
    background-size:                    100%;
    position:                           absolute;
    z-index:                            99;
    overflow:                           hidden;
    margin-top:                         7%;
    margin-left:                        5%;
    -moz-border-radius:                 20px;
    border-radius:                      20px;
}

.caption-text {
    max-width:                          460px;
    overflow:                           hidden;
    margin:                             20px;
}

.wrapper .slider-container #slideshow { 
    position:                           relative; 
    width:                              100%;
    float:                              left;
}

.wrapper .slider-container #slideshow > div { 
    position:                           absolute; 
}
```

The slider-container div should have 100% height so that the main-content div comes below it.

Thanks for in the advance!

Comment: At some level, this cascade of 100%s needs to have an ancestor with explicit height.

Comment: The slider should be dynamic so that its fluid

Comment: For `.slider-container` to have % height, you need to give its parent an explicit height, say 500px. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to say 100%, since the engine doesn't know what it value it should take a percentage of.

Comment: Here's a link to the site so you could see whats wrong, http://www.k2stuc.nl/test

Comment: but when it has an height for example of 500px how can the layout be fluid?

Comment: you can set the height dynamically say 
var myheight = $(window).height()

Comment: what kind of code is that?

Comment: that's jquery - can you show the html as well so we can see the DOM not just the css - are you using javascript at all - you can set just using plain ole js as well

Comment: You can see the code at http://k2stuc.nl/test/ I'm not familiar with js or jquery, the slider i created is built with a tutorial

Comment: why do you have width:100% on each image - it's best not resize images using css

Answer (score 16):

The `%` unit is always relative to some value .. even though you've specified `height: 100%;` on your `<body>` you will notice it ends up being 0px tall as are all the `<div>` that you gave 100% height to, because those values are relative to its parent container, which ends up being the root `<html>` element which currently has no explicit height set, so it defaults to `auto`. If you give the root element `height: 100%;` you will get the expected behaviour

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, in this case the slider-container div has an height of 100% but it's not clear 100% of what, but when I give html 100% height nothing changes?

Comment: This did change something, but now there is a big gap between the slider and content div http://www.k2stuc.nl/test/

Comment: Get rid of `min-height: 100%;` on slider-container

Comment: The gap is also different in various browsers

Comment: Its because you haven't cleared your floats .. you floated the content area and the slider left and didn't clear them so they remain out of the page flow. Hence why the body and html height doesn't include the content area even though its 100%

Comment: Wow, youre going a little fast, what do i need to fload and what not?

Comment: But when I do that yhe slider will come on top of everything?

Comment: Ok that placed the slider in its position

Comment: How can i make it so the body recocnizes the contect div?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a height to:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%; 
}

        </style>
```